# Forcing a signal on an interface (RS-232)

Tags: serial-port, modbus

Firstly, this may be a stupid question or one that has been asked before but I am not quite sure how to google it.

I try to learn a bit about using modbus to communicate over serial interfaces and I have trouble understanding the mechanic of getting your signal on the wire/connection. I do unterstand how protocols (e.g. Modbus) encode and decode their Data. I'm interested in the process of getting your bitcode through the interface (preferably rs232) to the other machine.

In other words: How can I write a piece of code myself (no libraries etc. I want to learn how to do it) where I can input a couple of binary numbers and maybe the baudrate so that another device with a working modbus driver can receive it via direct cable connection.

If the matter is too complicated for an answer here, I'd be happy to get a link to some resources to teach myself as well. Or even some help for the right search terms.

Comment: @Alex F: first of all, thank you for helping me. I've read the specifications and Implementations guide already and either I missed the relevant information or it isn't quite the answer to my problem. Maybe be I just don't know enough about serial communication programming. Maybe it wasn't clear enough in my question. I'm just trying to build a program that changes the voltage at the connector aka map the highs and lows in my chosen time interval.

Comment: To be more specific: i want this communication as lightweight and direct as possible. I do want the most control i get of the signals reaching the other device.